# How to train the bigger version of SSD(600x600?) in tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

The given config files for the ssd models has 300x300 as input sizes.
I would like to train the model with the bigger version to try to get a better accuracy as was said in the paper. How do I do this? Do I simply change the values in the config file or is there a specific way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeap u just have to modify that parameter before training.